# Accessing downloaded shapefiles/attribute data?

Tags: qgis-3

Using 3.8, I am attempting to create a simple map of the UK showing the county boundaries, with a couple of specific locations shown for reference. My approach for attempting this has been to attempt to download shapefiles from [here](https://data.gov.uk/search?q=county+boundaries&filters%5Bpublisher%5D=Ordnance+Survey&filters%5Btopic%5D=&filters%5Bformat%5D=&sort=best) plus a few other sources. The download appears to work well and I extract the data to a new folder.

Using Add Vector, I select the .shp file of relevance and a layer duly appears in the panel. However, nothing appears in the viewer. Similarly, when selecting the layer and clicking View Attribute Table, nothing appears in this table. Using the editing tools also does not highlight anything.

There are two possible explanations, 1) I am missing a vital (and probably simple) step in the download and import process, involving the specification of attributes, or 2) there is no visible attribute table within the downloaded packet.

This is not a projection nor viewing error as far as I can ascertain.

How do I incorporate attributes when importing such downloaded data?

---

I attach an image of the files in the folder as it was extracted from the sip file. I was aware that the shape files are made up of several types of file, but was under the impression there was additional information needed other than what is in this image. I also attach an image from the same download of a larger folder. I am happy to make these data available but would need further instruction regarding how to do this on the forum without breaking rules.

[larger dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l92Rp.png)[image: smaller dataset]

---

I downloaded additional data using the link in the comments, as well as downloading the original data a second time. I attach a screenshot. Still nothing is visible, irrespective of whether the projection is present or not. I will attempt a reinstall otherwise.

[image: QGIS screenshot]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the extracted files that you downloaded?  Do you already know that a shapefile is made up of 4-6 separate files?  i.e. a shapefile named test would have the following files: test.shp, test.dbf, test.prj, test.shx, test.cpg -  just trying to determine if you're missing something.  the download link you provided appears to provide an esri shapefile, which should import into QGIS without issues (i didn't download because I don't want to sign up).

Comment: Can you make these data available so we can take a look at them?

Comment: You can also download administrative boundaries for any country in the world from gadm.org. Here's a [direct download link](https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/shp/gadm36_GBR_shp.zip) for the UK boundaries as a zipped shapefile. The accuracy and resolution of this dataset may not be as good as the one provided by the official UK government website.

Comment: Shapefile format *includes* the dBase file; it is not an extra

Comment: those files are too small - my local copy is .shp 50Mb .dbf 12Kb - so try down loading and extracting again

Comment: I agree with Ian Turton, the 1kb size of all your file seem bad, either your download/extraction goes wrong or the original downloadable data are bad/empty

Comment: The GADM layers should be polygons, but in your screenshot the Layers panel shows that QGIS thinks they're points. They work fine for me, I just download them, unzip the zip file, and click and drag all four of the files that end in .shp into QGIS. I wonder if something is going wrong for you during the unzipping process.

Comment: I also noticed in your screenshot that the .shp file has the QGIS logo as its icon. It probably means at some point you tried to open a .shp file directly, and you told windows to use QGIS as the default program to open that type of file. I have no idea if that would cause this kind of problem, but it does seem unusual.

Comment: @csk I will attempt to download fresh data and update. Certainly I have not knowingly mis-labelled the data or allocated a default program. However, it is possible, hence a fresh attempt.

Comment: I've also attempted to find a method of 'unallocating' a program from a specific file extension, in this case the shape files, but have not been successful so far.